# Ошибки внутри метода doInBackground

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, null

Метод на строчке `listRubrics.setAdapter(entryRubricsAdapter);` выдает `NullPointerException`. Непонятно почему, так как этот же код без дополнений (второго `DownloadEntryNewsListTask` и того что дальше идет) работал нормально.
genreList почему-то не заполняется.

Еще выскакивает таинственный

```
Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

хотя я запускаю интернет соединение не в основном потоке, а в AsyncTask.

В чем причина ошибки?

вот код:

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import ru.ria.net.ContentGenerator;
import ru.ria.net.EntryNews;
import ru.ria.net.EntryRubrics;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listRubrics;
    //Диалог ожидания
    //private ProgressDialog pd;
    public static String ENTRY_NEWS = "com.example.alexander.ria";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listRubrics = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listRubrics);
        new DownloadEntryGenresListTask().execute();
        listRubrics.setOnItemClickListener(new ListViewClickListener());

    }

    private void showNewsList(List<EntryNews> entryNews) {
        System.out.println("ВЫЗВАН!");
        Intent intentEntryNews = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
        intentEntryNews.putExtra(ENTRY_NEWS, (Serializable) entryNews);
        startActivity(intentEntryNews);
    }


    private class DownloadEntryGenresListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EntryRubrics>> {
        List<EntryRubrics> genreList = null;
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        protected List<EntryRubrics> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
                ContentGenerator generator = new ContentGenerator();
                genreList = generator.getEntryRubrics();                           // этот блок кода вообще не запускается
                pd.dismiss();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return genreList;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<EntryRubrics> result) {
            EntryRubricsAdapter entryRubricsAdapter =
                    new EntryRubricsAdapter(MainActivity.this, genreList);
            System.out.println(genreList); // выдает что genreList = null !
            listRubrics.setAdapter(entryRubricsAdapter);
        }
    }

    private class DownloadEntryNewsListTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<EntryNews>> {
        private EntryNewsAdapter entryNewsAdapter;
        private ProgressDialog pd;
        private String ref;

        List<EntryNews> newsList;

        public DownloadEntryNewsListTask(String ref, List<EntryNews> newsList) {
            this.ref = ref;
            this.newsList = newsList;
        }

        protected List<EntryNews> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Working...", "request to server", true, false);
                ContentGenerator generator = new ContentGenerator();
                newsList = generator.getEntryNews(ref);
                pd.dismiss();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return newsList;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<EntryNews> result) {
            entryNewsAdapter =
                    new EntryNewsAdapter(MainActivity.this, newsList);
            listRubrics.setAdapter(entryNewsAdapter);
        }
    }

    class ListViewClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            EntryRubrics rubric = (EntryRubrics) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
            rubric.setNumber(position);
            ContentGenerator generator = new ContentGenerator();
            List<EntryNews> news = null;
            new DownloadEntryNewsListTask("http://ria.ru" + rubric.getSectionRef(), news).execute();

            // вызов нового активити с этим листом новостей
            showNewsList(news);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Запускать диалог прогресса, как и трогать другие View нельзя в `doInBackground`, т.к. в нём нет прямого доступа к UI потоку. Используйте `onPreExecute()` метод класса `AsyncTask`.
2. Убирать его так же надо не в `doInBackground` а в `onPostExecute()`
3. Присваивать данные переменной таска `doInBackground` также не следует. Просто возвращайте полученные данные из `doInBackground` и присваивайте их переменной класса в `onPostExecute()`.
4. Вместо `MainActivity.this` лучше передавайте ссылку на активити (Context) в конструктор таска.
5. Вызов `showNewsList(news);` не имеет смысла (как я понял) т.к. он не ждёт выполнения запущенной задачи и при его запуске news всегда будет `null`. Используйте `onPostExecute()` запущенной задачи.

Comment: `Просто возвращайте полученные данные из doInBackground и присваивайте их переменной класса в onPostExecute().`

Простите но как? явно вызывать doInBackground() в onPostExecute() не имеет смысла. Где мне получить ссылку на возвращенные данные с doInBackground() чтобы присвоить их переменной класса genreList ?

Comment: @АлександрДворцов, вы возвращаете сейчас из `doInBackground` `newsList = generator.getEntryNews(ref);`. Эти данные приходят в `onPostExecute` в качестве аргумента `result`